# transform pandas table from 1 column to 2

Tags: python, pandas

Using tabula I read pdf file and got a table:

```
data = {'country_code':  [123, 124, 125, 127, 128, 'city_', 'code', 211, 221, 223, 224, 'store_', 'NA', 'code', 321, 3231, 3213, 32123],

    }

what_i_have = pd.DataFrame(data)

what_i_have
```

[image]

There some NaN values(tha't not a problem) and some titles moved down(that is a problem).

I'd like to get something like this:
P.S. names of types are not important. I just want to differ codes

[image]

Comment: You'll probably have better luck building a better initial data structure than using pandas to fix that one. Posting your tabula code would help make this solvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need pandas to fix the issue , the idea still be split the word and number into two columns

```
df.country_code = df.country_code.replace('NA','')
t = pd.to_numeric(df.country_code,errors = 'coerce').isna()
s = df[t].reset_index()
s = s.groupby(s['index'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()).agg({'index':'first','country_code':'sum'}).set_index('index')
df['New'] = s['country_code'].reindex(df.index).ffill().fillna('country_code')

df = df[~t]

   country_code           New
0           123  country_code
1           124  country_code
2           125  country_code
3           127  country_code
4           128  country_code
7           211     city_code
8           221     city_code
9           223     city_code
10          224     city_code
14          321    store_code
15         3231    store_code
16         3213    store_code
17        32123    store_code
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df = df.dropna()
df["type"] = df.where(df["country_code"].str.contains("_", na=False)).ffill().fillna("country_")+"code"
df["country_code"] = pd.to_numeric(df["country_code"], errors="coerce")
df = df.dropna()

>>> df
    country_code          type
0          123.0  country_code
1          124.0  country_code
2          125.0  country_code
3          127.0  country_code
4          128.0  country_code
7          211.0     city_code
8          221.0     city_code
9          223.0     city_code
10         224.0     city_code
14         321.0    store_code
15        3231.0    store_code
16        3213.0    store_code
17       32123.0    store_code
```

###### Input df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country_code': [123, 124, 125, 127, 128, 'city_', 'code', 
                                    211, 221, 223, 224, 'store_', np.nan, 'code', 
                                    321, 3231, 3213, 32123]})
```

Comment: Thank you!!:)))

Comment: Happy to help! :)